# How to create an awaitable method properly

Tags: c#, async-await

I am writing some awaitable methods and I found a lot of way to do so on the internet. So I came here to know what is really happening on each way, and if some ways must be banished.

As far as I know, there is two kind of awaitable methods:

### Those which call other awaitable methods :

```
public async Task<Foo> GetFooAsync()
{
    var foo = await TrulyGetFooAsync();

    // Do stuff with foo

    return foo;
}
```

I did not find any other way to do this and I think it is the right way. Tell me if I am wrong !

### Those which only call non-awaitable methods :

And here the problems come in my mind.

For example, I saw this:

#### Exemple 1

```
public async Task<Foo> GetFooAsync()
{
    return await Task.Run(() => TrulyGetFoo());
}
```

As far as I understand, the async/await keywords are useless and can be avoided to give this:

#### Exemple 2

```
public Task<Foo> GetFooAsync()
{
    return Task.Run(() => TrulyGetFoo());
}
```

This last example is what I was doing until now. About that, is there a difference between:

```
Task.Run(() => TrulyGetFoo());
```

and

```
Task.Run((Foo)TrulyGetFoo); // I don't know if the cast is required at any time but in my code, it was
```

???

But I recently found this way:

#### Exemple 3

```
public Task<Foo> GetFooAsync()
{
    TaskCompletionSource<Foo> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Foo>();
    tcs.SetResult(TrulyGetFoo());
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

If I understood properly, an awaitable method does not always run on another thread ??? My guess is the third example is providing this mecanism (but how ??? I only see synchronous code in the third example), when the examples 1 and 2 will always run on a worker thread ???

May be there is still another ways to write awaitable methods, so let me know about them.

Comment: the other way: public Task<Foo> GetFooAsync() { return TrulyGetFooAsync(); }

Comment: Yes, of course. I have simplified too much this example and your remark is right. I will edit my question to clarify !

Comment: "I only see synchronous code in the third example" - it is completely synchronous. Task will be return already is completed state. You can do the same with `return Task.FromResult(TrulyGetFoo())` in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For example, I saw [`Task.Run` wrappers around synchronous code]

[This is a bad practice](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/03/24/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/). I have a blog post that explains [why `Task.Run` should not be used as a method implementation](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html).

> As far as I understand, the async/await keywords are useless and can be avoided

Yes, but [I don't recommend eliding `async`/`await` in more complex methods](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html).

> I recently found [`TaskCompletionSource<T>`]

As noted in the comments, your code example is still synchronous.

To make it asynchronous, your code should *start* some operation and return `TaskCompletionSource<T>.Task`. Then later, whenever that operation completes, your completion handler should call `TaskCompletionSource<T>.SetResult` (or similar method). For an example, see [TAP wrappers for EAP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873178(v=vs.110).aspx#EAP) or [TAP wrappers for `WaitHandle`s](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873178(v=vs.110).aspx#WHToTap).

`TaskFactory.FromAsync` is also a wrapper around `TaskCompletionSource<T>`, and is used for [TAP wrappers for APM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873178(v=vs.110).aspx#ApmToTap).

Comment: I am reading your `A Tour of Task` articles, provided by Sir Rufo on the other answer. This, plus all the links in your answer, I have un bunch of interresting readings for today.

Answer (score 3):

The short version is this: **anything that returns a Task can be awaited inside an `async` code block**.

```
public async Task MyAsyncMethod()
{
    // do some stuff
    await TrulyAsyncFoo();
    // do some other stuff
    return;
}
```

If awaiting the async call is the only thing the method does, you can simply return the task itself, which will be awaited "upstream":

```
public Task MyAsyncMethod()
{
    return TrulyAsyncFoo();
}
```

As far as calling synchronous (non-async) code in an async method, there's nothing to it. Just call it like normal code:

```
public async Task MyAsyncMethod()
{
    MySyncMethod();
    await TrulyAsyncFoo();
    MyOtherSyncMethod();
}
```

Doing `Task.Run(() => Foo())` is almost always a code smell that you aren't doing async/await right. Writing async code is not the same thing as writing multithreaded code. Async is just a nice way of telling the compiler that you need to wait for some network- or IO-bound task to complete.

To sum up:

- Await lets you write asynchronous and synchronous code side-by-side
- Async should only be used to wait for network- or IO-bound tasks, not compute-bound tasks
- Async methods should always return `Task` or `Task<T>`
- Avoid `async void`
- Avoid blocking using `task.Wait()` and `task.Result` in ASP.NET and other threaded applications unless you know what you are doing

Comment: a good resource for async/await/task is the blog from Stephen Cleary https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/04/a-tour-of-task-part-0-overview.html

Comment: `If awaiting the async call is the only thing the method does, you cansimply return the task itself` > As I said to Sir Rufo in the comments of the question, I have simplified too much the sample. I just edited my question for a better example. `There is usually no need for Task.Run(() => Foo()) or other complex syntax. That's almost always a code smell that you aren't doing async/await right` > As you said `usually`. So what if I still need it ?

Comment: From Sir Rufo link: `developers who have used Task in the past tend to try to use it the same way in the async world (which is wrong)` I guess I fell into the trap more than onces. The two links are really very interesting. Thanks !

Comment: @fharreau I clarified my answer a little. Calling a sync method shouldn't need `Task.Run` - what are you trying to do, specifically?

Comment: I am implementing in two different ways an interface with methods returning a Task. One implementation is using under the hood awaitable methods, so I do not have problem. The other implementation only use non-awaitable methods, so how can I write this implementation ? Just with `Task.FromResult()` ? The application I am working on is a WPF application. I don't want my UI to be frozen during the call.

Comment: @fharreau Yes, you can use `Task.FromResult` to return a Task from a synchronous method. Dealing with threading in a WPF application is a slightly different topic with its own "gotchas" though, so you may want to post another question with the details of what you are trying to do in WPF.

Answer (score -3):

I am using this for async events that manipulate my DB

```
private async void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

             success = await someClass.someMethod(some args);

    }
```

and the someMethod is a task like that:

```
public static async Task<someObject> someMethod(args)
    {
       //do something here
    }
```

Comment: How does this answer the question from above?

Comment: `async void` should be avoided unless absolutely necessary.