# Can this code work as asynchronous?

Tags: c#, async-await

I want to run GetAnswerToLife method to wait for 5 seconds and then print 210 while "for loop" is printing the numbers. But below code only prints the for loop and I can not make this async method work. 210 is not seen anywhere. Is there anything I am missing here?

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication30
{
internal class Program
{
    private static async Task<int> GetAnswerToLife()
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        int answer = 21 * 10;
        return answer;
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }

        int a =  GetAnswerToLife().Result;
        Console.WriteLine(a);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: this is working for me fine.

Comment: It works but they are not working asynchronously. After for loop finishes printing, after that 210 is printed. What I want it for loop and other method starts at the same time.

Comment: Why do you expect they will run simultaneously? The for loop is finished even before you wait for the GetAnswerToLife method.

Comment: What can I do to make them start at the same time then?

Comment: Starting at the same time is impossible. One (or even more) cpu cycle minimum time gap

Comment: @Lyrk , I think you are confused, check my answer for more details.

Comment: To help you see what is going on, add some `Console.WriteLine()` statements and output the time.  Check out [this](https://ideone.com/lwkP2w) to see an example.  Also you say that '210' is not seen anywhere, but isn't it printed at the end 5 seconds after the for loop completes?  I've decreased the delays by a factor of 10 and added logging the time down to the millisecond so you can see the order of events in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It works but they are not working asynchronously. After for loop
>   finishes printing, after that 210 is printed. What I want it for loop
>   and other method starts at the same time.

I think you are confusing asynchronous work with parallelism. Asynchronous is doing work , but not blocking the thread , once your thread hit `await` it actually is released to the thread pool to do some other job, while waiting for the statement after `await` to evaluate, only after this the execution continues.

Parallelism is where work is done in parallel, hence the name of the action.

Consider this as an example.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Parallel.Invoke(PrintLoop, async () => Console.WriteLine(await GetAnswerToLife()));
        }

        public static void PrintLoop()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        }

        public static async Task<int> GetAnswerToLife()
        {
            await Task.Delay(5000);
            return 21 * 10;
        }
    }
}
```

Now 210 will be printed somewhere between numbers 1 and 100, which is different and I think this was what you wanted initially.

@Stephen Cleary [explanations](https://blog.stephencleary.com/) about async operations are really off the chart, you should definitely check as a further readings.

Comment: @downvoter , can you explain please

Comment: thank you for the answer. This really cleared.

Comment: @Lyrk I've added further reading link if you are interested.

Answer (score -1):

You are calling the `GetAnswerToLife` after the loop. Obviously, it will be executed after the loop.

If you want the answer to life computed in the same time as your loop, call it before the start of the loop:

```
private static async Task<int> GetAnswerToLife()
{
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    int answer = 21 * 10;

    Console.WriteLine(answer);

    return answer;
}

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var answering = GetAnswerToLife();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }

    // Calling .Result will ensure the answer has been calculated
    int a = answering.Result;
}
```

I also changed your answer to life implementation so it prints the answer in console in order to know the answer when it is done calculating and not at the end of the loop.

Comment: Because it is a small calculation, can I omit  this part?                                
"int a = answering.Result;"

Comment: If you do not need the result, why do you calculate it at all? BTW Task<T>.Result is a blocking operation and will return, whenever the Task is completed

Comment: You can, but you can't be sure the answer to life has been calculated. Basically, calling the `Result` property in a non-async method is like calling `await` in an async method. To be honest, I am not sure this is totaly true. There is probably a difference, talking about `AsyncContext` and things like that, but I never perfectly understand those things (looks for Stephen Cleary's articles on the subject if you want to know more about that)

Comment: If you are lucky, he can come here and explains all that stuff so much better than me :D.

Comment: @fharreau It has nothing to with async or non-async method. A call to Result will internally call Wait and that is blocking in **any** case

Comment: @SirRufo Can you explain why a new thread is created for execution after the `Task.Delay` in this case? Shouldn't it execute the rest of the code on the Main thread after finishing delay?

Comment: Afaik there is no thread created by this code. Everything will run on the same thread. This is just Syntactic sugar for the C# old fashion way of BeginAction and EndAction with a callback : https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/48/async-await#t=201708101359499080843

Comment: Sometime ago I ask this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43393169/how-to-create-an-awaitable-method-properly) and I got a lot of very goods links (by Sir Rufo who is present here and also by Stephen Cleary)

Comment: @fharreau there should be 2 threads created for this code. One main thread and one for the execution after Task.Delay. Hence, my confusion. I thought everything after Task.Delay will also be executed on the main thread.

Comment: @PiyushParashar This is special to a console application, because there is no real synchronization context the task can return to, so it will not return to the caller context

Comment: @PiyushParashar WPF/WinForms does have a real synchronization context which can be captured and therefore this code will work perfect in a console application, but can cause a deadlock in a WPF/WinForms application.