# Returning Task<bool> from LINQ's Any method?

Tags: c#, linq, asynchronous, task

I have this interface :

```
public interface ISign
{
   Task<bool> IsRegisteredCopy();
}
```

Implemented it:

```
public class Sign : ISign
    {
        TabibContext context = new TabibContext();
        public Task<bool> IsRegisteredCopy()
        {
            return context.Doctors.Any();
        }
    }
```

So I need to return Task from `Any` method which is not available!

Comment: `return context.Doctors.AnyAsync();`

Comment: not available in the IntelliSense!

Comment: Do you have the `System.Data.Entity` namespace imported?

Comment: Nope, thought it exist in `System.Data`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Entity Framework has various [async extensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.queryableextensions(v=vs.113).aspx) you can use in the `System.Data.Entity` namespace. So you can do this:

```
using System.Data.Entity;

public Task<bool> IsRegisteredCopy()
{
    return context.Doctors.AnyAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have several ways to do this. One of them is the Matthew Watson's way (`return Task.Run(() => context.Doctors.Any());`). It is not considered as a good practice (take a look at Stephen Cleary answers and links in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43393169/how-to-create-an-awaitable-method-properly)).

Here is another way that does not requires you to actually run a Task. You can return a Task without having a task like this:

```
return Task.FromResult(context.Doctors.Any());
```

This way, you can return a value without triggering all the task stuff. It is a better practice when you don't actually have a task in your methods.

Note: on the last version of Entity Framework, you have a `AnyAsync` methods which is even better:

```
public async Task<bool> IsRegisteredCopy()
{
    return await context.Doctors.AnyAsync();
}
```

You will need to add this using: `System.Data.Entity`;

Comment: Why would you `return await` when you could simply `return` ?

Comment: @EricLippert > While it is more efficient to simply return the Task (the compiler does not add all the await stuff), Stephen Cleary has a nice blog [article](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html) about that. Short answer: it is recommended to always use async/await for complex code. For example, when you use the `using` clause, the call to Dispose() can break something. The exception catching is also impacted by the moment you call await, etc.

Comment: @fharreau Just in case you didn't realise... Eric helped create C# so he's probably not asking you to explain to him :)